# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line (which doesn't exist)

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout, layout-inflater

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/has_selected_account"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_display_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_name_and_display_vertical_padding"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/account_menu_name_and_display_vertical_padding"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/account_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:text="DisplayNameIsLongSoItShouldBeTruncatedAtSomePoint"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_name_and_display_vertical_padding"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/account_menu_name_and_display_vertical_padding"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account_display_name"
        tools:text="emailisverylongaswellwewantittogettruncated@gmail.longdomain.com"/>
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</merge>
```

And I get a very general inflation error:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.me.AccountParticle
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(Layo
```

(Cut like this)

I have tried to simplify my XML. How can I tackle the inflation error?

Plus my layout XML doesn't have like #39
so where does this refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `android:layout_height` for both `TextView`, that's how you get view inflation error. When the view is being inflated, it needs to resolve the `merge` tag possibly by another class or method, which seems to have a different way of parsing errors. Otherwise you would have seen a clearer error with `android:layout_height` being missing.

Comment: how could i have debugged it?

Comment: It could have shown you a clearer error, but because of `merge` tag it can become unclear when it is delegated to whichever the class is parsing it.

Comment: so i could just paste the xml instead of using the merge.

Comment: Using merge is one way to optimize your views, and so it's fine using merge. I think the IDE or Android Studio should have given you the warnings when missing one of the important attributes. Maybe there's a plugin for it, but whenever there's a view inflation error, chances are it's within the XML layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/has_selected_account"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_display_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_name_and_display_vertical_padding"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/account_menu_name_and_display_vertical_padding"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/account_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:text="DisplayNameIsLongSoItShouldBeTruncatedAtSomePoint"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_name_and_display_vertical_padding"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/account_menu_name_and_display_vertical_padding"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account_display_name"
        tools:text="emailisverylongaswellwewantittogettruncated@gmail.longdomain.com"/>
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</merge>
```